# C# Index Out Of Range Exception when creating date

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have written a piece of code where it connects to SQL Server to retrieve some data from the database. One type of these data that I need is a stored date for something. This works fine, it connects and retrieves all the data I want from it, but when I try to create a `DateTime` using the retrieved date I've got from SQL it gives me a Index Out of Range Exception.

Here is the code for it:

```
//sDate contains 14/11/2014 so dateArr[0] contains 14, dateArr[1] contains 11 and dateArr[2] contains 2014

for(int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][9] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        String[] sDateAndTime = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][9].ToString().Split(' ');
        String sDate = sDateAndTime[0];
        String[] dateArr = sDate.Split('/');
        DateTime date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dateArr[3]), Convert.ToInt32(dateArr[2]), Convert.ToInt32(dateArr[1]));

        Console.WriteLine(dateArr[0] + " " + dateArr[1] + " " + dateArr[2]);
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that the error only comes up on line `DateTime date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dateArr[3]), Convert.ToInt32(dateArr[2]), Convert.ToInt32(dateArr[1]));`

If I comment that line out, it works totally fine. Can someone please let me know what is it that I'm doing wrong? I've tried all kinds of methods including using `DateTime.ParseExact` but it still doesn't work (give a different error).

Comment: What is the content of dateArr after the Split?

Comment: You're indexing elements 1, 2, and 3 instead of 0, 1, and 2 (like in the VERY NEXT LINE....).

Comment: @helrich I am such a god damn Idiot!

Comment: Just curios, what was the error using ParseExact? DateTime.ParseExact(sDate,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) should work in this case

Comment: @JoonasKoski The error for it was 'string not recognized valid datetime'. I've tried using that approach and it didn't work.

Comment: @Danny, Joonas' suggestion should definitely work and is also a much better option. Try to do it that way, it's much more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays indexes are 0 based. Try this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dateArr[2]), Convert.ToInt32(dateArr[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dateArr[0]));
```